# Dotted Line for PDF Rendering in iOS

Tags: ios, line, draw, cgcontext, dotted-line

I wont to know how to render a dotted line on a pdf.

```
CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(currentContext, [UIColor grayColor].CGColor);
CGFloat lengths[] = {0, 8};
CGContextSetLineCap(currentContext, kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(currentContext, 1);
CGContextSetLineDash(currentContext, 0.0f, lengths, 2);

CGContextBeginPath(currentContext);
CGContextMoveToPoint(currentContext, x1, y1);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(currentContext, x2, y2);

CGContextClosePath(currentContext);
CGContextDrawPath(currentContext, kCGPathStroke);
```

From what I understand, this code should produce a dotted line that has 0 units of painted (dot) followed by 8 units of unpainted line.  It does not.  It produces the following instead:

A dot followed by 8 units of empty space followed by a dot followed by 1 unit of empty space followed by a dot followed by 8 units of empty space...etc.  I would post the picture but I don't have enough rep points.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've found a weird quirk with pdfs. When dealing with them, I have to draw the pdf upside down because pdfs are upside down to UIKit corrdinates. Maybe your issue is related to this.

Comment: Does colorWithPatternImage work with pdfs?

Comment: @VGruenhagen Core Graphics does that, it's in the manual (Quartz2d if you wanna see)

Comment: @StephenJ I really don't want to use an image. According to the documentation, I am doing this right. I am just not getting the expected results.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does this not dot the line correctly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16547017/why-does-this-not-dot-the-line-correctly)